# Resources to learn openCV for android

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I am new to both android development as well as openCV. Meaning, I want to learn them... specifically I want to learn OpenCV for android..

Is it necessary to understand basic OpenCV first? What will be a proper way to learn? Can anybody please guide me? Also, let me know about good resources to learn the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these resouces
[OpenCV's own Android tutorials.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/table_of_content_introduction/table_of_content_introduction.html)

[Tegra Android Development Pack by NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack) contains more than ten example Android projects which use OpenCV. In the doc folder there is some explanation, but not for all of them. You have to register to NVIDIA and apply as Tegra Developer, which means filling a form with general information.

[Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)